# Resuming Training PyTorch

Tags: machine-learning, pytorch

I'm attempting to save and load best model through torch, where I've defined my training function as follows:

```
def train_model(model, train_loader, test_loader, device, learning_rate=1e-1, num_epochs=200):

    # The training configurations were not carefully selected.

    criterion = nn.CrossEntropyLoss()

    model.to(device)

    # It seems that SGD optimizer is better than Adam optimizer for ResNet18 training on CIFAR10.
    optimizer = optim.SGD(model.parameters(), lr=learning_rate, momentum=0.9, weight_decay=1e-4)
    # scheduler = torch.optim.lr_scheduler.CosineAnnealingLR(optimizer, T_max=500)
    scheduler = torch.optim.lr_scheduler.MultiStepLR(optimizer, milestones=[65, 75], gamma=0.75, last_epoch=-1)
    # optimizer = optim.Adam(model.parameters(), lr=learning_rate, betas=(0.9, 0.999), eps=1e-08, weight_decay=0, amsgrad=False)

    # Evaluation
    model.eval()
    eval_loss, eval_accuracy = evaluate_model(model=model, test_loader=test_loader, device=device, criterion=criterion)
    print("Epoch: {:02d} Eval Loss: {:.3f} Eval Acc: {:.3f}".format(-1, eval_loss, eval_accuracy))

    load_model = input('Load a model?')
    
    
    for epoch in range(num_epochs):

        if  epoch//2 == 0:
          write_checkpoint(model=model, epoch=epoch, scheduler=scheduler, optimizer=optimizer)          
          model, optimizer, epoch, scheduler = load_checkpoint(model=model, scheduler=scheduler, optimizer=optimizer)    
          
          for state in optimizer.state.values():
            for k, v in state.items():
                if isinstance(v, torch.Tensor):
                    state[k] = v.to(device)
        # Training
        model.train()

        running_loss = 0
        running_corrects = 0

        for inputs, labels in train_loader:
            inputs = torch.FloatTensor(inputs)
            inputs = inputs.to(device)
            labels = labels.to(device)

            # zero the parameter gradients
            optimizer.zero_grad()

            # forward + backward + optimize
            outputs = model(inputs)
            _, preds = torch.max(outputs, 1)
            loss = criterion(outputs, labels)
            loss.backward()
            optimizer.step()

            # statistics
            running_loss += loss.item() * inputs.size(0)
            running_corrects += torch.sum(preds == labels.data)

        train_loss = running_loss / len(train_loader.dataset)
        train_accuracy = running_corrects / len(train_loader.dataset)

        # Evaluation
        model.eval()
        eval_loss, eval_accuracy = evaluate_model(model=model, test_loader=test_loader, device=device, criterion=criterion)

        # Set learning rate scheduler
        scheduler.step()

        print("Epoch: {:03d} Train Loss: {:.3f} Train Acc: {:.3f} Eval Loss: {:.3f} Eval Acc: {:.3f}".format(epoch, train_loss, train_accuracy, eval_loss, eval_accuracy))

    return model
```

Where I'd like to be able to load a model, and start training from the epoch where model was saved.

So far I have methods to save model, optimizer,scheduler states and the epoch via

```
def write_checkpoint(model, optimizer, epoch, scheduler):
  state = {'epoch': epoch + 1, 'state_dict': model.state_dict(),
             'optimizer': optimizer.state_dict(), 'scheduler': scheduler.state_dict(), }
  filename = '/content/model_'
  
  torch.save(state, filename + f'CP_epoch{epoch + 1}.pth')


def load_checkpoint(model, optimizer, scheduler, filename='/content/checkpoint.pth'):
    # Note: Input model & optimizer should be pre-defined.  This routine only updates their states.
    start_epoch = 0
    if os.path.isfile(filename):
        print("=> loading checkpoint '{}'".format(filename))
        checkpoint = torch.load(filename)
        start_epoch = checkpoint['epoch']
        model.load_state_dict(checkpoint['state_dict'])
        optimizer.load_state_dict(checkpoint['optimizer'])
        scheduler = checkpoint['scheduler']
        print("=> loaded checkpoint '{}' (epoch {})"
                  .format(filename, checkpoint['epoch']))
        
        
    else:
        print("=> no checkpoint found at '{}'".format(filename))

    return model, optimizer, start_epoch, scheduler
```

But I can't seem to come up with the logic of how I'd update the epoch to start at the correct one. Looking for hints or ideas on how to implement just that.

Comment: you already knew everything that needed to restore the training state, just set the loaded epoch value to the intial one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand correctly you trying to resume training from last progress with correct epoch number.

Before calling `train_model` load the checkpoint values including `start_epoch`. Then use `start_epoch` as loop starting point,

```
for epoch in range(start_epoch, num_epochs):
```

Comment: That makes sense, I suppose I was looking for ways to essentially not use for loop with the range, to initialize your epochs because we cannot change the value of epoch within the loop. But this also seems like another way to approaching the same

Answer (score 1):

I see a few problems with your code

1. The learning rate scheduler is not restored correctly. You should change this line inside the `load_chekpoint` function

   `scheduler = checkpoint['scheduler']` to
   `scheduler.load_state_dict(checkpoint['scheduler']`
2. Why are you restoring from a checkpoint inside your epoch loop ?. I think you mean to restore from a checkpoint only when the training gets interrupted.
3. Why are you moving the tensors inside the optimizer to a device in this block.

   ```
               for k, v in state.items():
                   if isinstance(v, torch.Tensor):
                       state[k] = v.to(device)
   ```

I think this is unnecessary

I would structure your code something like this

```py
def train_one_epoch(model, train_loader, criterion, device, optimizer):
    model.train()
    running_loss = 0
    running_corrects = 0

    for inputs, labels in train_loader:
        inputs = torch.FloatTensor(inputs)
        inputs = inputs.to(device)
        labels = labels.to(device)

        # zero the parameter gradients
        optimizer.zero_grad()

        # forward + backward + optimize
        outputs = model(inputs)
        _, preds = torch.max(outputs, 1)
        loss = criterion(outputs, labels)
        loss.backward()
        optimizer.step()

        # statistics
        running_loss += loss.item() * inputs.size(0)
        running_corrects += torch.sum(preds == labels.data)

    train_loss = running_loss / len(train_loader.dataset)
    train_accuracy = running_corrects / len(train_loader.dataset)
    return train_loss, train_accuracy


def test(model, test_loader, criterion, device):
    size = len(test_loader.dataset)
    model.eval()
    num_batches = len(test_loader)
    test_loss, corrects = 0, 0
    with torch.no_grad():
        for inputs, labels  in test_loader:
            inputs = inputs.to(device)
            labels = labels.to(device)
            preds = model(inputs)
            test_loss += criterion(preds, labels).item()
            corrects += (preds.argmax(1) == y).type(torch.float).sum().item()
    test_accuracy = (corrects * 100) / size
    print("test loss:{} accuracy:{}".format(test_loss / num_batches, test_accuracy))
    return test_loss, test_accuracy


def train_model(model, train_loader, test_loader, device, checkpoint_path, learning_rate=1e-1, num_epochs=200):

    criterion = nn.CrossEntropyLoss()
    model.to(device)
    optimizer = optim.SGD(model.parameters(), lr=learning_rate, momentum=0.9, weight_decay=1e-4)
    scheduler = torch.optim.lr_scheduler.MultiStepLR(optimizer, milestones=[65, 75], gamma=0.75, last_epoch=-1)

    start_epoch = 0

    # load from checkpoint of it exists
    if os.path.exists(checkpoint_path):
        checkpoint = torch.load(checkpoint_path)
        model.load_state_dict(checkpoint['model_state_dict'])
        optimizer.load_state_dict(checkpoint['optimizer_state_dict'])
        scheduler.load_state_dict(checkpoint['scheduler_state_dict'])
        start_epoch = checkpoint['epoch']

    for epoch in range(start_epoch+1, num_epochs):
        train_loss, train_accuracy = train_one_epoch(train_loader, model, optimizer, criterion, device)
        scheduler.step()
        eval_loss, eval_accuracy = test(test_loader, model, criterion, device)

        # save checkpoint
        torch.save({
            'epoch': epoch,
            'model_state_dict': model.state_dict(),
            'optimizer_state_dict': optimizer.state_dict(),
            'lr_state_dict': scheduler.state_dict(),
        }, checkpoint_path)

        print("Epoch: {:03d} Train Loss: {:.3f} Train Acc: {:.3f} Eval Loss: {:.3f} Eval Acc: {:.3f}".format(epoch,
                                                                                                             train_loss,
                                                                                                             train_accuracy,
                                                                                                             eval_loss,
                                                                                                             eval_accuracy))
    return model
```

Comment: This is a certainly a lot cleaner than what I had originally written.